# Error while writing recovery offsets checkpoint in directory in kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to run kafka-server-start.bat but I get the below error:

ERROR Disk error while writing recovery offsets checkpoint in directory  C:\kafka_2.13-3.0.0\data\kafka.

Zookeeper runs in the background successfully

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Managed to fix this error by downgrade the kafka to version 2.8.1. Seems that windows are not working well with version 3.0.0